# Troubles with importing java package to scala project (IntelliJ 10.5.2)

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

Trying to add "import" statement to my new scala project (I'm using IntelliJ 10.5.2 right now) syntax highlighter tells me that he cannot find java package:

```
import java.util.zip //Cannot resolve symbol java

object Main extends App {

    override def main(args: Array[String]) {

    }
}
```

What's wrong. What should I do to import this package?

Comment: You should normally import java.util.zip._ (same as the * in java). Otherwise, you will have to do zip.ZipFile rather than ZipFile. But this is not your problem, this is for after you will have solved your problem. import java.util.zip is valid syntax.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure that you have a Java SDK configured under:

`File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Project SDK`

See [Where do I configure project JDK](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/migration_faq.html)

Comment: I'll note this advice is relevant in the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA, at this time, 12.

Answer (score 0):

File -> Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> SDKs -> change your JDK home path to the correct location of your latest JDK version.

In my case, the path was set as `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64`, so I changed it to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64` and all my imports suddenly went from red to white, and there were no more error warnings in my scala project due to unknown java classes/methods.

OBS: The errors shown by IntelliJ were purely graphical, since I could build my project. But when I built them, my red imports would be removed by the ide. After this fix the problems desapeared.

My IntelliJ configuration:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-193.6015.39, built on January 21, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.5+10-b520.30 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-74-generic
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1998M
Cores: 6
Registry: 
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.intellij.scala
```